# Modifying pointer leads to SIGSEGV signal

Tags: c++, class, pointers, sdl, segmentation-fault

this is my first experience,so don't be picky.
It's SIGSEGV problem, and it appears only in class linking.
The problem within "SDL_surface *ScreenSurface" pointer.

Here goes the code...

**Screen header**

```
class screen
{
public:
    screen();
    SDLclass_Window *MainWindow=NULL;
    SDL_Surface *ScreenSurface=NULL; //this is the problem pointer to the struct that cause error
    //Those pointer are't NULL, see below
    virtual ~screen();
protected:
private:
    const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1280;
    const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 726;
    bool init();
};
```

**Screen code**

```
screen::screen()
{

if(!init())
    {
        std::cout<<"ERROR at INIT";
        SDL_Delay( 4000 );
    }
else
    {
    bool quit=0;
    SDL_Event e;
    while (!quit)
        {
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(MainWindow);

            //Looking for events
            while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
            {
                //User requests quit
                if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }


this->~screen();
}
bool screen::init() //Initialization
{
    bool succses=1;
    if (SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        std::cout<< "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error:"<< SDL_GetError()<<std::endl;
        succses=0;
        return succses;
    }
    MainWindow= SDL_CreateWindow( "Arachy: WIP Version", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN ); //Setting parameters to SDL_window
    if (MainWindow==NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<"can't create window"<<SDL_GetError()<<std::endl;
        succses=0;
        return succses;
    }
    else
    {
        //Get window surface
        ScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( MainWindow );// telling ScreenSurface that it our main screen surface
    }

    return succses;
}

screen::~screen()
{
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

**Activity header**
(another class that uses SDL_Surface which defined above in class Screen)

```
class activity
{
public:
    activity();
    virtual ~activity();
protected:
private:
    screen mainScreen;
    void load();

};
```

**Activity code** (I'm trying to modify SDL_Surface with SDL_FillRect() after that i got SIGSEGV signal during debug

```
activity::activity()
{

    SDL_FillRect(mainScreen.ScreenSurface,NULL,SDL_MapRGB(mainScreen.ScreenSurface->format,255,000000,255));
}
```

Please , help me to find out...
Thank you

Comment: You put your main event loop in your constructor and explicitly call the destructor from it? That's ugly. What are you trying to do?

Comment: it's a raw code that definitely will be cleaned, i'm creating a demo graphical app for study needs

Comment: As set now, `activity`'s constructor body will never be called until the main event loop is over.

Comment: Oh, thank you a lot .You right,it was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is twofold:**

**A)** It's likely that the destructor of `screen` is called twice, causing SDL_DestroyWindow() and SDL_FreeSurface() to be called on invalid, non-NULL pointers.

If you absolutely, positively want to call your destructor twice, you should at least reset these pointers to NULL after destroying the objects they point to.

But in most cases you should simply, you know, *not* explicitly call the destructor...

**B)** As set now, `activity`'s constructor body will never be called until the main event loop is over.

Comment: Ok, I'll put it away.I just started to develop this and i still trying to make it works